What is the difference between roots and zeroes?
Suppose I have a polynomial of degree 6. It crosses the x-axis at 3 distinct points, and the graph of the polynomial touches the x-axis at one of those 3 points (a repeated root).
Question 1: What is the total number of roots of the polynomial?
My answer: It should be 6, because the question doesn’t specify whether the roots should be real or complex.
Question 2: What is the number of zeroes of the polynomial?
My answer: It should be 4 because it crosses the axis at 3 points and one of them is repeated.
Question 3: What is the total number of solutions to $P(x)=0$ where $P$ is the equation of the polynomial?
My answer: 3
Are all of my answers correct?

To my understanding, there is no distinction. Your concern seems to be whether one allows for repetition; in my experience, we explicitly state whether roots/zeroes are allowed to repeat or state their multiplicities whenever the context is relevant.

What is the source of this question?  Typically, we don't really get hung up on the distinction between "roots", "solutions", and "zeros".  If this is from some text or assignment, then the author of that text or assignment is getting hung up on this distinction, and you need to ask them what kind of answers they are expecting.  Otherwise, I don't think that any of your answers are really sufficient---e.g. the polynomial has 6 complex roots, counting with multiplicity

A distinction once made is that equations have roots while expressions have zeros. Thus, $-2$ and $3$ are the roots (in $x$) of the quadratic equation $x^2-x=6$, while they are the zeros of the quadratic polynomial $x^2-x-6$. While I prefer to keep this distinction, it is often not made. There is no distinction between roots and zeros in regard to multiplicity.

They're isomorphic, since a zero is simply the root of the equation where the expression equals 0. And you can turn an equation into an expression simply by subtracting one side of the equal sign from the other.

I'm not sure this is accurate. Surely expressions/functions have zeros and equations don't (because equations don't have values). But I would be hesitant to say equations have roots either; if there's an equation I would call those solutions (values of the variable(s) that make the equation true).

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE : There's nothing wrong with solutions of an equation. However, the OP asked specifically about roots. This term has long been in use, particularly in regard to quadratic, cubic, and higher-order equations: for example, “every cubic equation has a real root”.

Do you have any citation for your claim that "equations have roots while expressions have zeros"?  This runs very counter to the sources I can find:  equations definitely have solutions, and the word "root" is equivalent to "solution".  Functions have zeros, but some sources use "zero" and "root" synonymously.  Even so, I don't think that there is any real consensus.  See, for example, my previous answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4896924/ .
